# No Facebook log in for StackExchange Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, openid

StackExchange Data Explorer allows login with about a dozen open IDs, but, unlike every other Stack Exchange site (in my understanding), Facebook isn't offered as one of the options.

[image]

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Facebook authentication is done via OAuth 2.0, but Data Explorer is currently only set up to handle OpenID authentication. However, most of the heavy lifting is done with the help of [DotNetOpenAuth](http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/), so adding support for OAuth logins is entirely possible - it just hasn't been done yet.

Since [Data Explorer is open source](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/), if someone is really interested in having this functionality they're more than welcome to go add it to [the relevant controller](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/source/browse/App/StackExchange.DataExplorer/Controllers/AccountController.cs). Otherwise, provided there's enough interest in this request, I'll put it on my to-do list and see what I can do about getting it taken care of.

Comment: MyOpenID is still a recommended login path for Data.SE? Interesting. Also, Tim, I dislike the fact that your login buttons have no hover effect. Please fix.

Comment: I would appreciate adding FB login functionality to data.SE.  I don't want to have to remember which account I use to log into which SE site.

Comment: Any updates regarding this? Was something done? People [keep asking](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231542/how-to-login-on-data-stackexchange-com-using-facebook). :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I can probably look at this next, yeah

Comment: So, 6 to 8 weeks? :D

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm waiting on a login-related PR to go through, after which I should be able to do this relatively easily.

Comment: Funny I can login in meta using Facebook find this question. but not can log in dataexchange.:(

Comment: @canon might take infinity, as not enough people want/need it. One request  every few months isn't enough.

Comment: @canon well, we can keep poking poor Tim here,  but so far it didn't really help.  *sadder face*