# Is there a way to select the "current user" in the SE Data Explorer?

Tags: support, data-explorer

Looking at the existing queries on Data Explorer, it seems that folks typically use a "parameter" to input the SE user id for their queries. Is there a way in the explorer SQL to access the user id of the person logged in at the time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As explained in the [help section on query parameters](https://data.stackexchange.com/help#parameters), using the `##UserId##` parameter in your query will cause Data Explorer to auto-populate the field with the suspected user ID of the currently logged-in SEDE user on the given site, based on a match of their email hash with the email provided in their Data Explorer profile.

This isn't fool-proof, of course, so I'm thinking of trying to work some [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/) integration in, but for now this is the best you can do.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't experiencing that auto-complete behavior because I wasn't logged in!

Comment: And FWIW, I wasn't logged in because Facebook login wasn't an option and that's what I used for all my SE sites. I didn't want to create "another" SE login, but I eventually did and learned that it used my email address to find the matching account.

Comment: Yeah, adding login support for Facebook is [a requested feature](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141685/no-facebook-log-in-for-stackexchange-data-explorer) which will hopefully be added sooner than later.

Comment: @TimStone - incidentally, this has never worked for me - but it's a non-issue to me since autofill (in Firefox) remembers the text box's history, as long as I spell/capitalize "`##UserID##`" (or other parameters) the same every time.